# Fast Left Joins

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join, create-table, xeround

I recently switched from using a local MySQL instance to using a Xeround MySQL instance for my C# application. As such, I've noticed that queries run much more slowly. I'm currently running a left join to create a new table and am trying to shave a few seconds off my run time.

I've observed the following average run times:

- CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT ): 14s
- CREATE TABLE & INSERT LEFT JOIN: 14s
- SELECT statement only: 9s
- CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS (SELECT ): 9.2s
- CREATE VIEW & Retrieve Contents: 9.5s

Currently I am running the `CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT)` statement. Obviously, I would like to shave off the five second premium associated with moving from a select statement only, to a `CREATE TABLE` with a select statement. Using views seemed promising, but accessing data from the view is extremely slow, and doesn't justify the time savings here. Using a temporary table also seems promising, but with the way that I am making my function calls, the table will get deleted before I finish accessing it. Is there another keyword I can use to tell the MySQL engine to take the contents of a `SELECT` statement and put it into a barebones table?

Comment: Are you sure your tables have indexes set up?

Comment: Yes. These numbers are from testing with indexes on the fields being joined.

Answer (score 0):

The 5-seconds delay seems to be induced by the writing of the selected records into your table. If free memory allows, try creating your table with the `MEMORY` engine:

```
CREATE TABLE myTempTable ENGINE=MEMORY AS SELECT (...)
```

As for the worse performances compared to your local server (assuming similar hardware specs), I would advise comparing the output of `SHOW VARIABLES` on each system, especially those variables beginning with "innodb_".